# Como detectar se wi-fi e/ou bluetooth estão ligados

Tags: android, spring-security, bluetooth

Boa tarde!
Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece algum código fonte aberto para uma aplicação checar se o wi-fi ou Bluetooth estão ligados.

Comment: Tomara que você não esteja pedindo que faça um app pra você (kkk)

Comment: repetindo a pergunta, pois acho que não ficou claro...Boa tarde Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe se tem alguma aplicação com o código fonte aberto que checa se o wi-fi ou Bluetooth está ligado desnecessariamente.

Comment: Olá Klever. Eu até tinha votado pra fechar como fora de escopo, mas retirei o voto porque você já teve uma resposta útil. Ainda assim acho que seria bacana você editar a pergunta pra, ao invés de pedir código fonte aberto, solicitar como se faz o que você quer no Android. Sei que na prática dá no mesmo, mas potencialmente gera respostas melhores e assim a pergunta se torna mais útil para a toda a comunidade.

Comment: Mais uma vez, Boa tarde Gostaria de saber se alguém sabe se tem alguma aplicação com o código fonte aberto= Onde no texto diz que pedi o código fonte: "perguntei se alguém sabe de uma APLICAÇÃO que tenha o seu código fonte disponível. Abs

Answer (score 3):

Com base no meu comentário e acreditando que você tem conhecimento sobre o que solicita, mostro-lhe esse código fonte aberto que analisa se o **wi-fi está ligado**.

```
private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "NetworkStatusExample";
ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) 
        getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI); 
boolean isWifiConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
networkInfo = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
boolean isMobileConn = networkInfo.isConnected();
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Wifi conectado: " + isWifiConn);
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "3G conectado: " + isMobileConn);
```

---

### Fonte: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html

**Código fonte aberto para Bluetooth**

- Não há maneira de recuperar uma lista de dispositivos conectados na inicialização do aplicativo. A API Bluetooth não permite que você consulte, em vez disso, permite que você veja as mudanças.
- Um trabalho hoaky seria para recuperar a lista de todos os dispositivos emparelhados conhecidos / ...então tentar ligar para cada um (para determinar se você está conectado).
- Alternativamente, você pode ter um controle de fundo com a API Bluetooth e escrever os estados do dispositivo.

  ```
  public void onCreate() {        
  IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
  IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
  IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
  this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
  this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
  this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);
  }


  private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      String action = intent.getAction();
      BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

      if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
         ... //Device found
      }
      else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
         ... //Device is now connected
      }
      else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
         ... //Done searching
      }
      else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
         ... //Device is about to disconnect
      }
      else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
         ... //Device has disconnected
      }           
  }
  };
  ```

**Não se esqueça da permissão:** 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

---

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715865/how-to-programmatically-tell-if-a-bluetooth-device-is-connected-android-2-2

---

Comment: Valeu...na verdade tenho uma aplicação, na qual checa alguns itens de segurança do sistema, mas queria do dispositivo, exemplo: "olha você seu  Bluetooth está ligado ou o wi-fi quer deixar ligado". Abs

Comment: Não se esqueça da permissão: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`